# How to Show colors related to products using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I trying to show product color related to product I already have made a relation  tables into database i just only want to know that when i click the specific product the color related to that product will be shown.thanks

I am facing error how to fix it ?
 https://flareapp.io/share/VmeXLq5Q#F56

Does anybody have an idea ?

**product_color model**

```
          class Product_color extends Model
          {
          public function products()
          {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'available_product_color', 'product_color_id', 
         'product_id');
          }
          }
```

**product model**

```
           class Product extends Model
           {
           public function sizes()
           {
           return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product_sizes', 'available_product_sizes', 'product_id', 
          'product_size_id');
            }

         public function color()
         {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product_color', 'available_product_color', 'product_id', 
        'product_color_id');
         }

         }
```

**controller**

```
       public function single_product($product_slug)
       {       
      $single_product = Product::with('sizes','color')->where('product_slug',$product_slug)->first();      
      return view('front_end/single_product',compact('single_product'));
       }   
       }
```

**HTML VIEW**

```
                <div class="form-group product__option">
                <label class="product__option-label">Color</label>
                <div class="input-radio-color">
                <div class="input-radio-color__list">
                @foreach($single_product->color as $color)   
                <span><img src="{{$color->color_image}}"></span>
                @endforeach                                                    
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your code is searching for table with name `product_colors`, check if you have that, also I will suggest you to go into documentation for naming convention for pivot table, if you are not sure about how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly suggest to stick to camel casing when it comes to naming your classes. Its a really good convention and helps. so ideally `Product_color` should be `ProductColor` or at least `Product_Color`. That also helps laravel to find the relevant information quite easily. As per laravel convention, your pivot table should be named in alphabetical order, so as the letter `C` comes before `P`, it should be called `ColorProduct` otherwise specify the name of table in the model

```
class Product_color extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'available_product_color ??';

  public function products()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
         'App\Product', 
         'available_product_color',
         'product_color_id', 
         'product_id'
     );
   }
 }
```

Here is the link to documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many